# Trying to show inventory with Steam API

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

So I just started with this API, and I am stuck on this part for about a day.
I want to show all of the inventory items (Code below has a var_dump).

PHP Code:
    $data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $steamprofile['steamid'] . '/inventory/json/753/6');
    $result = json_decode($data);
    var_dump($result);

JSON Result: www.pastebin.com/5WXQX7WN 
I cut away the last part because the result was to long :)

Is there anyone that fixed this problem, or might know a solution?

P.S. $steamprofile['steamid'] is the steam64id from a steam account.

Comment: You need to use the instance id/ class id with [getAssetClassInfo](https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamEconomy_GetAssetClassInfo_v1) to pull the item description

Comment: You got any examples?

Comment: I've never worked with the steam API before so no I don't have any examples.. Just foreach loop your `$result` and send another api request to the above method to get the info you need